# Using a wildcard in Excel forumla

Tags: excel, wildcard

We are using the following formula to pull in numerical values for all fields which contain the word "component".

```
=SUM(('Client Data'!$D$2:$D$100=B40)*('Client Data'!$C$2:$C$100="component")*('Client Data'!T$2:T$100))
```

I am trying add a wildcard so that this formula also looks for any fields which contain more than the word "component". For example, words such as "component request", "component change" are included in the search.

Please can you advise if this is possible and how i can achieve this?  Changing "component" to `*component*` in the above formula doesn't work.

Apologies If i haven't explained this question well.

Thanks
Kirsty

Comment: Any of these functions use wildcards: http://www.exceluser.com/excel_help/functions/guide-to-excel-wildcards.htm

Answer (score 0):

While *SUMPRODUCT()* does not directly implement wildcards, it is possible to fake it:

Here is one way to implement a "wildcard" within *SUMPRODUCT()* to make column **C include** "component":

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Client Data'!$D$2:$D$100=B40)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("component",'Client Data'!$C$2:$C$100,1))*('Client Data'!T$2:T$100)))
```

From: [chitosunday post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=34683)

Answer (score 0):

SUMIFS should work with in this scenario.

```
=SUMIFS('Client Data'!T$2:T$100,'Client Data'!$D$2:$D$100,B40,'Client Data'!$C$2:$C$100,"*component*")
```

Comment: Thank you, i will give this a try